# Why isn't this expect script matching this glob pattern (debug included)

Tags: expect

This section of my expect script is sometimes sending "y\r", and sometimes not.  On a side note, I don't even see why `lvcreate` is asking, because before here, the script `dd`'s 20GB of zeros to the drives, and this is the first lvcreate.  But, whatever, what would be a separate question, and I'd just rather build in the response for wiping.  (And, yes, this type of thing is dangerous.  It's for fresh system installs, and steps through with the user to get them to type in several confirmations.)

I don't get why it's not matching on the first glob.  First line is the actual output of the program `lvcreate`.

```
WARNING: linux_raid_member signature detected on /dev/disk1/terraswap1 at offset 4096. Wipe it? [y/n]: 
expect: does "\u001b[K\u001b[?1h\u001b=\u001b[?2004hl\u0008lvcreate disk1 -L 16G -n terraswap1\u001b[?1l\u001b>\u001b[?2004l\r\r\n\u001b]0;root@archiso: lvcreate disk1 -L 16G -n terraswap1\u0007WARNING: linux_raid_member signature detected on /dev/disk1/terraswap1 at offset 4096. Wipe it? [y/n]: " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Wipe it? [y/n]: "? no
"root*archiso*# "? no
```

In short, to reduce scrolling, the expect output is:

```
expect: does "...Wipe it? [y/n]: " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Wipe it? [y/n]: "? no
"root*archiso*# "? no
```

The pertinent code section is:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# ... connect via ssh as root to machine with hostname archiso

expect "root*archiso*# "
send "lvcreate disk1 -L 16G -n terraswap1\r"
expect {
   "Wipe it? \[y/n]: " {
      send "y\r"
      exp_continue
   } "root*archiso*# " {
      send "lvcreate disk2 -L 16G -n terraswap2\r"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[` is special to both `Tcl` and the `Expect` pattern matcher so it is particularly messy. To match a literal `[`, you have to backslash once from `Tcl` and then again so that it is not treated as a range during pattern matching. The first backslash, of course, has to be backslashed to prevent it from turning the next backslash into a literal backslash!

```
expect "\\\[" ; #matches literal '['
```

So, your code should be,

```
expect {
   "Wipe it? \\\[y/n]: " {
      send "y\r"
      exp_continue
   } "root*archiso*# " {
      send "lvcreate disk2 -L 16G -n terraswap2\r"
   }
}
```

**Note :**

Alternatively, we can use braces as well for matching literal `[`

```
expect {\[}; # This too matches literal '['
```

Answer (score 0):

glob patterns are implicitly anchored. Your pattern does not match because the *entirety* of the text does not match the short pattern. For a string *containing* "Wipe it? [y/n]", you want:

```
{*Wipe it\? \[y/n\]:*}
```

Note that `?` is a glob wildcard, so escape it to match a literal question mark. See the [string match](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M35) documentation for details.